# What is the difference between getting a reference and creating a new instance of an object?

Tags: c#, unity

I asked a question a while ago and got an answer that I can either get a reference to the object or create a new one, like the below example:

```
Example myExample = get some reference to the object/create a new() one

myExample.testing; // or if it is private use a get method for it.
```

Whats the difference between the two examples above (get a reference and create a new one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer:**

The main difference between getting a reference to an object and creating a new object is how many objects you end up with and how they behave when you manipulate them. When creating a new object you end up with one more object than you had before.

**Expanded Answer:**

There are some behaviors in code that you need to be aware of to know when you need multiple objects vs multiple references to an object.

First, if you have multiple objects you will use up more memory. This usually isn't a big deal if you're just creating one object, but if you're creating a new instance of an object each time you iterate though a loop that executes thousands of times... It may or may not be a problem depending on what is all happening. It also may or may not be required.

Second there is some behavioral differences you need to be aware of. Consider the below example.

```
Person p1 = new Person("John");// original person
Person p2 = new Person("Jill");// another instance of a person
// change the age on each person
p1.SetAge(23);
p2.SetAge(45);
// print each person's age
Console.WriteLine("p1 age: " + p1.GetAge());
Console.WriteLine("p2 age: " + p2.GetAge());
```

This will have the below output:

```
p1 age: 23
p2 age: 45
```

Now we'll do the same thing except `p2` will be a reference the the instance `p1`.

```
Person p1 = new Person("John");// original person
Person p2 = p1;// a reference to an existing person
// change the age on each person
p1.SetAge(23);
p2.SetAge(45);
// print each person's age
Console.WriteLine("p1 age: " + p1.GetAge());
Console.WriteLine("p2 age: " + p2.GetAge());
```

Here's where you might get tripped up. The output is below.

```
p1 age: 45
p2 age: 45
```

Wait a minute. That can't be right... or can it? Let's look at what happened. We said `p1` is a person named "John." Then we said `p2 = p1`. This is saying that `p2` is also "John." Think of it as an alias (because that's exactly what it is). If you were to pause a debugger at any point after setting both variables, you could see that in the second example both `p1` and `p2` point to the same location in memory. Therefore changing one of them changes both of them.

**Which is better**

This really depends on your needs. Look at how you want the object to behave in your program and make a decision. If you find out you made the wrong one, just switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable

```
Gameobject reference = existing_gameobject
```

then operations that you'll do on `reference` will apply to `existing_gameobject`.

If you create a new `GameObject` you will interact to a brand new one instead.

Coming back to the previous example, if you do

```
reference.transform.position += Vector3.Right
```

the position of the `existing_gameobject` will be modified. If you create a new one

```
GameObject newGO = new GameObject();
```

and then

```
newGO.transform.position += Vector3.Right
```

you will modify just the `newGO` position.